# Android SQLite Update not working

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to update one column for any number of rows.

Here is the function:

```
public void setAwardsSyncComplete(String[] ids) {

    String inArray = StringUtils.separateCommas(ids);
    db.beginTransaction();

    try {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_SYNCED, true);

        int rowsAffected = db.update(TABLE, contentValues, COL_ID + " IN (" + inArray + ")", null);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        DebugLog.e("Error in transaction", e.toString());
    } finally {

        db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

What is strange is that the rowsAffected returns correctly (i.e. rowsAffected > 0), but the column values remain *null*.

Am I overlooking something very simple here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you're using transactions, you need to call db.setTransactionSuccessful(); at the end of the try clause. Without this, the update gets rolled back.

See [SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29)

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `db.setTransactionSuccussful()` after `db.update` otherwise any changes will be rolled back when you call `endTransaction()`.

Answer (score 1):

there's no explicit boolean type in sqlite tables?
what data type is the COL_SYNED column you are trying to update?

and you will need to call db.setTransactionSuccussful()

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem on your update..

You need to loop your array and update each one by one..

```
    private int _rowsAffected;

    foreach (var a in inArray)
    {

    _rowsAffected= db.update(TABLE, contentValues, COL_ID + " = (" + a +")", null);

    }

    db.Commit();
    db.setTransactionSuccussful(); 


if(_rowsAffected > 0)
//Success
```

Regards