# what is the update statement pattern in android SQLite to add a value the field?

Tags: android, sqlite

my code is as follows, but it seems not working.

```
public void update(int mixId, long startPos, int count) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("update downloadedFragement set downloadedLength=downloadedLength+? where mixId=? and startPos=?", 
            new Object[]{count, mixId, startPos});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the doc on the [execSQL()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method:

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

You should use the [update()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) method instead

Comment: Yes, it is right to use the update() method, but it seems not easy to add a value to the original value using update method.

Comment: I'm not sure but you can attempt to use the method rawQuery() with the sql statement from your question. See this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[]). Otherwise you would need to do a query followed by an update.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by surrounding it with:

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    //do stuff, including execSQL()
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5575277/6027