# Increase a column value in sqlite without the method execSQL

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'd like to update one of my table's column with the following query:

```
update TABLE set COLUMN_NAME= COLUMN_NAME+1;
```

using if posible the

```
update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

method in SQLiteDatabase class in android
Is that posible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the data type of COLUMN_NAME? Is it INTEGER? If it is, as long as the query is not faulty you can do it.

Comment: yes is a integer, but if I use 
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_COUNT , KEY_COUNT+1); it fails

Comment: Yes it is. Just specify the `whereClause`, it might cause exceptions if you leave it null/incorrect statement. Set it something like `"id_=?"`

Answer (score 0):

though this is a bit overdue, i'm just adding an example that works...

```
SQLite version 3.7.9 2011-11-01 00:52:41
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table test1(a int primary key, b int);
sqlite> begin transaction;
sqlite> insert into test1(a,b) values (1,4);
sqlite> insert into test1(a,b) values (2,5);
sqlite> insert into test1(a,b) values (3,4);
sqlite> commit;
sqlite> select * from test1;
1|4
2|5
3|4
sqlite> update test1 set b=b+1;
sqlite> select * from test1;
1|5
2|6
3|5
sqlite> update test1 set b=b+10;
sqlite> select * from test1;
1|15
2|16
3|15
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have some luck with execSQL. Here's what I did to solve a similar problem:

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    //do update stuff, including execSQL()
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5575277/6027